# Specify point type for RGeo-ActiveRecord column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, postgis, rgeo

there is a typical schema when `Address` model has an RGeo attribute:

```
t.st_point :coordinates,   geographic: true, srid: 4326
```

and normally it is wrapped in the `RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl` class

```
Realty.last.address.coordinates
#<RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl:0x2b1a364b429c "POINT (106.5 10.5)">
```

but in some situations, it is wrapped with completely inappropriate Cartesian wrapper `RGeo::Cartesian::PointImpl`

```
Realty.joins(:address).select('realties.id, addresses.coordinates::geometry').first.coordinates
#<RGeo::Cartesian::PointImpl:0x2b1a364a691c "POINT (106.0 10.0)">
```

I'm using latest `'activerecord-postgis-adapter 3.1.4'` with `rails 4.2.4`

Maybe anybody know how a way to fix this, i.e. make `coordinates` always return instance of `RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl`?

Answer (score 2):

When you select the column with `addresses.coordinates::geometry`, you are forcing Postgres to return a column of type geometry. When you do `Realty.last.address.coordinates`, you are returning a different SQL type (a point).

I would remove the `::geometry` from your SQL query.

From the docs at https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo-activerecord#spatial-factories-for-columns:

`activerecord-postgis-adapter` converts the SQL type to a ruby type using the `SpatialFactoryStore` class as the registry to lookup types.

Register spatial factories in the `SpatialFactoryStore` singleton class. Each spatial type in your ActiveRecord models will use the `SpatialFactoryStore` to retrieve a factory matching the properties of its type. For example, you can set a different spatial factory for point types, or for types matching a specific SRID, or having a Z coordinate, or any combination of attributes.

The supported keys when registering a spatial type are listed here with their default values and other allowed values:

```
geo_type: "geometry", # point, polygon, line_string, geometry_collection, 
                      # multi_line_string, multi_point, multi_polygon
has_m:    false,      # true
has_z:    false,      # true
sql_type: "geometry", # geography
srid:     0,          # (any valid SRID)
```

The default factories are `RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory` for geographic types, and `RGeo::Cartesian.preferred_factory` for geometric types.

Here is an example setup:

```
RGeo::ActiveRecord::SpatialFactoryStore.instance.tap do |config|
  # By default, use the GEOS implementation for spatial columns.
  config.default = RGeo::Geos.factory_generator

  # But use a geographic implementation for point columns.
  config.register(RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326), geo_type: "point")
end
```